# Access method of private class inside static inner class from main()

Tags: java

I have a private method inside private class which resides inside `static` inner class. I want to access that method from `main()` method. I have created a silly  example to give it a clear understanding.

```
public class Thanos{
   public static void main(){
       //get Gamora here
   }
   static class Avengers{
       private class StarLord{
           private void getGamora(){
               System.out.println("Access me to get a soul for a soul.");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Below is how I reached inside the **Avengers** class but the class **StarLord** just don't allow me to access the **getGamora** method.

```
//inside main() method
Avengers avngrs= new Thanos.Avengers();
//here create instance of StarLord class
```

The only intentions of **Thanos** class is to get the soul string of **getGamora** method as output.

**Output**

```
Access me to get a soul for a soul.
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a `StarLord` by using `avengers.new StarLord()` as follows:

```
public class Thanos{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Avengers avengers = new Thanos.Avengers();
        Avengers.StarLord starLord = avengers.new StarLord();
        starLord.getGamora();
    }
    static class Avengers{
        private class StarLord{
            private void getGamora(){
                System.out.println("Access me to get a soul for a soul.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```